# Convert array to a string with newlines embeded in string

Tags: arrays, perl

i need to convert a perl array to a single string variable, containing all array items separated with newlines.

```
my $content = "";
@names=('A','C','C','D','E');
$content = $content . join($", @names) . "\n";
print $content;
```

I intend the output to be like:

```
A
C
C
D
E
```

But i get:

```
A C C D E
```

Why isn't the newline `\n` character being honoured?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it appears that you want a newline not just between each line, but after the last one too, you can use any of the following:

```perl
join("\n", @names) . "\n"
```

```perl
join("", map "$_\n", @names)
```

```perl
join("\n", @names, "")
```

These are equivalent except when the array in empty. In that situation, the first results in a newline, and the other result in an empty string.

---

By the way,

```
 $content = $content . EXPR;
```

can be written as

```
 $content .= EXPR;
```

Comment: There is a slight difference: If the array is empty, `join("", map "$_\n", @names)` produces `""`, not `"\n"`.

Comment: I usually just do e.g. `join("\n", @array, "")`

Answer (score 3):

To join an array with newlines in between, use

```
join("\n", @array)
```

Your code uses the contents of the `$"` variable as the separator, which by default contains a space.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
$content = $content . join("\n", @names);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$"` variable holds the value that Perl uses between array elements when it interpolates an array in a double-quoted string. By default (and you haven't changed it), it's a space.

Perhaps you were thinking about the input or output record separators, `$/` or `$\`.

But, you don't really want to play with those variables. If you want a newline, use a newline:

```
join "\n", @array;
```